# Strategy interface that can return instances of implementing class

Tags: java

I have a class of this type

```
@Value(staticConstructor="of")
public class PolicyOne {

    public static Policy of (String scope ) {
        return PolicyOne(scope);
    }

    private final String scope;
}
```

and can create instances like this  `PolicyOne.of(“hello”)`

I’m trying to implement strategy design pattern.

How can i define an equivalent abstract method  in the strategy interface for that “of ()” method so that when i pass the interface implementation (PolicyOne or PolicyTwo) to another class and it can call policyStrategy.of(“someValue”)

```
public interface PolicyStrategy {

      // what should be the method signature for “of” method?
      // return type needs be of the implementation class type

}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can't use an Interface to declare static methods, you need to have an instance

Comment: It sounds like you want to couple a factory pattern to produce concrete strategy instances. If these concrete strategy implementations are directly associated with 'scope' values, then you may want to create an enum class to represent 'scope' values and find your factory methods to those enum values.

Comment: @fab Not true starting with Java 8.

Comment: @mre okay, it is possible since java8 ... but you shouldn't use it for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation class is determined solely on the basis of the given 'scope' string, [using enums as factories](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/i-figured-out-how-cleanup-my-java-code-using-enums-factories-drake/) will solve your problem nicely. Click through to this linkedIn article for a comprehensive solution to this problem. But, I've excerpted and applied this solution to your problem here:

```
public class ReallyGreatPolicy implements Policy {}
public class TotalRipoffPolicy implements Policy {}

public enum PolicyType {
    ReallyGreat {
        @Override
        Policy createPolicy() {
            return new ReallyGreatPolicy();
        }
    } ,
    TotalRipoff {
        @Override
        Policy createPolicy() {
            return new TotalRipoffPolicy();
        }
    },
    ;
    abstract Policy createPolicy();

    public static Policy of (String scope ) {
        return PolicyFactory.valueOf(scope).createPolicy();
    }
}
```